# How to recycle unity scroll list of game objects?

Tags: unity, scrolling

In my game, I have a scrollrect which its content have a VerticalLayout component. When I fill that with so many count of GameObjects, the game will fall in problem!

I know that I have to recycle my objects, but I don't know how!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @SP When I load game rooms in a list, there are too many game object (about 5000) instantiated, and cause memory leak.